# Win32 c++: Get process CPU affinity?

Tags: c++, process, cpu, affinity

I need to query the CPU affinity of my program and find how many CPUs from the total number of CPUs available to the system are assigned to it.

`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns a value that doesn't reflect affinity. Is there a (fast) way to query process affinity?

Comment: There's  no portable way to do it. But if you search for Windows API functions to find it out you should find plenty of examples, of which quite a few might even exist here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is working:

```
int getAffinityCount()
{
    DWORD64 dwProcessAffinity, dwSystemAffinity;
    GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), &dwProcessAffinity, &dwSystemAffinity);
    return __popcnt64(dwProcessAffinity);
}
```

Comment: Note that `GetProcessAffinityMask()` is specific to Windows only, so this solution is not portable to other platforms.

Comment: That's ok, as per my title I'm looking for a windows solution.